# auth error using gqlgen and gin returns an empty response

Tags: authentication, go, error-handling, gqlgen

There are no recipes for this which is surprising as it seems like a pretty basic use case.

If a request does not have a valid token, we want to return a 403 to the user.  But trying to do that results in an empty response and "missing response context" error.

So this is currently the middleware:

```
    func (auth \*Auth) Middleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c \*gin.Context) {
             _, err := auth.Validate(c.Request.Context(), c.Request)
             if (err != nil) {
                  c.AbortWithError(http.StatusForbidden, err)
                  return
              }

            c.Next()
        }

     }
```

Using it here in server.go

```
    func Register(config \*viper.Viper, broker \*broker.Broker, metrics \*metrics.Metrics,   clients    *clients.Clients, auth \*auth.Auth) {
        //...
        r.Use(auth.Middleware())

        //...
    
        r.POST("/query", graphqlHandler(broker, clients, metrics))
        r.GET("/query", graphqlHandler(broker, clients, metrics))
        r.GET("/", playgroundHandler())
   
        _ = r.Run()

    }
```

There is no response returned in the event of an invalid token and you get:

> missing response context

I was thinking I could use `graphql.WithResponseContext` but since that's immutable and we are aborting so there is no "next", there is no place for that context to go.